# getting combined result in sql

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible the get result like this from 2 tables `products` and `products image` relation table...

i am using php. i can orginize data with php, but i want to get data in this form using sql because of performance..  i know the sql join but it gives the simple array data. i need data as array in array.

`Products` table:

```
id   name     
1    product1        
2    product2
```

`images` table:

```
product_id  imageid
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           4
2           5
2           6


[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                )
        )
```

Comment: yes. use an sql join: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: i know sql join but it not gives the result array in array..it gives just simple array with relation

Comment: that's not the DB's fault. that's your fault for not structuring your "fetch" code properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long.  Your data structure looks like it is from Perl; it might have been worth noting that in your question (e.g. "I'd like to get the data into a Perl data structure similar to this:", and possibly with a Perl tag).  It's also usually worth mentioning the DBMS you're using, though the answer will be much the same regardless.  SQL DBMS do not understand how you want Perl to organize your data; you would have to convert the simple list returned by the DBMS into the structure you desire.  It's not very hard, though it is not trivial.

Comment: thank you for your answers. i am using php. i can organize data with php as i want but i want to learn getting data with sql like my structure. 

i think, sql do not gives the data structure as i want (array in array). İ wantted to learn is it possiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get an array within an array as the result directly from a relational (SQL) database.

You'll need to loop over the results and create the array yourself, e.g.

```
$productsById = array();

foreach ($dbRows as $row) {
    if (!isset( $productsById[$row['product_id']] )) {
        $product = array(
            'id' => $row['product_id'],
            'name' => $row['product_name']
        );
        //note the use of the & to set the $product array by reference
        $productsById[$row['product_id']] = &$product;
    }
    //note the use of the & to retrieve the $product array by reference
    else $product = &$productsById[$row['product_id']];

    $product['images'][] = array(
        'id' => $row['image_id']
    );

    //We unset this because we accessed it by reference above; this prevents referencing the wrong product
    //on the next iteration of the loop.
    unset($product);
}
```

Or, to get an array of objects:

```
$productsById = array();

foreach ($dbRows as $row) {
    if (!isset( $productsById[$row['product_id']] )) {
        $product = new stdClass;
        $product->id = $row['product_id'];
        $product->name = $row['product_name'];
        $product->images = array();
        $productsById[$row['product_id']] = $product;
    }
    else $product = $productsById[$row['product_id']];

    $image = new stdClass;
    $image->id = $row['image_id'];
    $product->images[] = $image;
}
```

It's also worth mentioning, however, that if you're using MySQL (and database portability isn't a concern), you can make use of the GROUP_CONCAT function, e.g.:

```
SELECT p.id as product_id, p.name as product_name, GROUP_CONCAT(i.id) as image_ids
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN image i ON p.id = i.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Then in your PHP, you'd have only one $row array for each product, and you could get the image IDs simply by using:

```
$imageIds = explode(',', $row['image_ids']);
```

Comment: There was a bug in my first example above; I've now corrected it.

Comment: This of course assumes that every product has images; if not, you'd need to check `empty($row['image_id'])` to test if there was an image ID or not before adding it to the images array.